# Deep NLP pipeline with Whoosh

Tags: python, nlp, information-retrieval, whoosh

I am very new to NLP and IR programs. I am trying to implement a deep NLP pipeline i.e. adding Lemmatizing, Dependency parsing features to the indexing of sentences. Following is my schema and searcher.

```
my_analyzer = RegexTokenizer()| StopFilter()| LowercaseFilter() | StemFilter() | Lemmatizer()
    pos_analyser = RegexTokenizer() | StopFilter()| LowercaseFilter() | PosTagger()
    schema = Schema(id=ID(stored=True, unique=True), stem_text=TEXT(stored= True, analyzer=my_analyzer), pos_tag= pos_analyser)

for sentence in sent_tokenize_list1:
    writer.add_document(stem_text = sentence, pos_tag = sentence)
for sentence in sent_tokenize_list2:
    writer.add_document(stem_text = sentence, pos_tag = sentence)
writer.commit()
with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    og = qparser.OrGroup.factory(0.9)
    query_text = MultifieldParser(["stem_text","pos_tag"], schema = ix.schema, group= og).parse(
        "who is controlling the threat of locusts?")
     results = searcher.search(query_text, sortedby= scores, limit = 10 )
```

This is the custom analyzer.

```
class PosTagger(Filter):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (other
                and self.__class__ is other.__class__
                and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

    def __init__(self):
         self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, tokens):
         assert hasattr(tokens, "__iter__")
         words = []
         tokens1, tokens2 = itertools.tee(tokens)
         for t in tokens1:
            words.append(t.text)
         tags = pos_tag(words)
         i=0
         for t in tokens2:
             t.text = tags[i][0] + " "+ tags[i][1]
             i += 1
             yield t
```

I am getting the following error.

> **whoosh.fields.FieldConfigurationError: CompositeAnalyzer(RegexTokenizer(expression=re.compile('\w+(\.?\w+)*'),
>   gaps=False), StopFilter(stops=frozenset({'for', 'will', 'tbd', 'with',
>   'and', 'the', 'if', 'it', 'by', 'is', 'are', 'this', 'as', 'when',
>   'us', 'or', 'from', 'yet', 'you', 'have', 'can', 'be', 'we', 'of',
>   'to', 'on', 'a', 'an', 'your', 'at', 'in', 'may', 'not', 'that'}),
>   min=2, max=None, renumber=True), LowercaseFilter(),
>   PosTagger(cache={})) is not a FieldType object**

Am I doing it a wrong way? Is this the proper way to add NLP pipeline to search engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pos_tag` should assigned to a field `TEXT(stored= True, analyzer=pos_analyzer)` not to the `pos_analyser` directly.

So in `schema` you should have:

```
schema = Schema(id=ID(stored=True, unique=True), stem_text=TEXT(stored= True, analyzer=my_analyzer), post_tag=TEXT(stored= True, analyzer=pos_analyzer))
```